# How to call a controller method from a link in a view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Blocked by the fact that **OVH** can't deploy .Net websites, we have turned to use Laravel (to use MVC).

so I have created a controller and  I need to call it's methods from my layout, I tried this :

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{action('HomeController@WhoWeAre')}}"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>
```

where HomeContoller is my controller, and WhoWeAre is a method.

when I run my app, the website crash and I get this message :

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 589: Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@WhoWeAre not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

How can that be corrected, please?

Comment: Hi, HomeController.php is in "App\Http\Controllers" directory?

Comment: yes , it is in that folder .

Comment: do you have function  public function WhoWeAre() {...} on HomeController.php .

Comment: yes as i mentionned i add it after creating the controller

Comment: What's your laravel version?

Comment: And did you run "php artisan route:clear" after editing routes/web.php?

Comment: my laravel verion is 5.1.46 , i didn't edit web.php

Comment: Please try following
- Route
Route::get('/WhoWeAre', 'HomeController@WhoWeAre')->name('WhoWeAre');
- View
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('WhoWeAre') }}"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201378/discussion-between-darany-khiev-and-a-haddad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is just add a  new route in web.php :

```
Route::get('/whoweare', 'HomeController@WhoWeAre');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

- Route

```
Route::get('/WhoWeAre', 'HomeController@WhoWeAre')->name('WhoWeAre');
```

- View

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('WhoWeAre') }}"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>
```

Comment: that dosen't work but by simply adding a route in web.php  the error disappear